# Notepad++ - Break Line after a word

Tags: notepad++

I have some text I want to edit using Notepad++.

The text input is

```
google.comyahoo.com
doctor.comusa.com
```

I want the text output is

```
google.com
yahoo.com
doctor.com
usa.com
```

Thanks for read and help

Comment: @Karan You'd have seen that if you had looked at the Markdown source. :) FTFY.

Comment: Please add a little bit more info: Is this a search and replace? (find:".com" replace with ".com\n") Is this a copy/paste from another source and you want it to automatically add the \n for you? If we know the context and how you are using NPP, we might have a better chance at answer your question.

Comment: Oh, dang! I could have gotten an "Answer" point!!?! hahaha...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple Search/Replace option, you can choose "[MENU] > Search > Replace" and find: `.com` and replace it with: `.com\n`. Make sure your "Search Mode" in the "Replace" tab has "Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)" selected.